# Does MediaWiki have a News extension?

Tags: mediawiki

Many CMS' have news on the front page, where e.g. the sysop/webmaster posts about down time and other important news.

Often these can be scheduled, so that you e.g. write on Monday, and wants it to be visible  from Tuesday to Friday.

**Question**

Does MediaWiki have something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `#switch` function to do this. There are some examples on this article - [generating dynamic content with mediawiki](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Generating_dynamic_content_with_MediaWiki).

The documentation on `#switch` is here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#.23switch

Answer (score 0):

The "dpl" (Dynamic Page List) extension can also be used for that.

We use the following to display a random page from our site on our landing page. With DPL, you can filter that to a specific category, or filter by myriad other means.

```
<dpl>
namespace=
includepage=*
includemaxlength=600
escapelinks=false
resultsheader=__NOTOC__ __NOEDITSECTION__
randomcount=1
mode=userformat
addpagecounter=true
listseparators=<h2>A Random Selection From Page: , [[%PAGE%]]</h2>,,\n\n
</dpl>
```